# Yii2 Render Page from a function

Tags: yii2

I have created an rest calling framework in YII2. In this I have a class APIRequest From this class I want to render a page if I get an error from API.

My code:

```
public static function response($response,$serviceObject)
{
    if($serviceObject->responseCode == 420)
    {
        $errorMessage   =   $response->errorMessage;
        return \Yii::$app->getView()->renderFile('@app/views/merchants/error.php',['errorMessage'=>$errorMessage]);
    }
    else 
    {
        return $response;
    }
}
```

But this is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much information to go on. where is this method invoked? in the controller class?

perhapse this could help http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-handling-errors.html

Comment: No it is invoked in another class

Answer (score 0):

Generally the Yii REST API doesn't use any views. See

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html

Comment: OK, than what is the error exactly? Where is this function? In a controller? Please provide the appropriate controller section.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
return \Yii::$app->view->renderFile('@app/views/merchants/error.php',['errorMessage'=>$errorMessage]);
```

instead of

```
return \Yii::$app->getView()->renderFile('@app/views/merchants/error.php',['errorMessage'=>$errorMessage])
```